# What does the Hash (#) sign mean after two equal signs (==#) in vim

Tags: vim

I cam across the below code at [enter link description here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters#Twiddle_case) and what it does is toggle the words in a visual selection from UPPER CASE, then to lower case, then to Title Case. I am trying to change this functionality into toggling the words from Title Case to lower case, then to UPPER CASE. The problem is I have no idea what `==#` means here. Can someone please provide an answer as to what `==#` is.

```
function! TwiddleCase(str)
  if a:str ==# toupper(a:str)
    let result = tolower(a:str)
  elseif a:str ==# tolower(a:str)
    let result = substitute(a:str,'\(\<\w\+\>\)', '\u\1', 'g')
  else
    let result = toupper(a:str)
  endif
  return result
endfunction
vnoremap ~ y:call setreg('', TwiddleCase(@"), getregtype(''))<CR>gv""Pgv
```

Comment: It's explained in `:help ==#`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`==#` is the "always case-sensitive" comparison operator (plain `==` depends on `:set ignorecase`).

For more information, see [Vimscript cheat sheet](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/vimscript.html).

Comment: Adding to this, using `:help <the thing I am curious about>` has a very high success rate in Vim ;-) Typing `:help ==#` did not disappoint :-)